# how to create a `directed` bar chart

Tags: charts, code-request

This code was developed by @Jagra:

```
ClearAll\["Global`*"\];
countries = CountryData\["G7"\];
data = {{2, 1, 1.5, 3, 3, 2.5, 4}, {-2, -1, -1.5, -3, -3, -2.5, -2}};

Column\[{
  TextCell\["GDP Per Capital", "Section", FontColor -> White\],
  TextCell\["This is a scenario parameter set", FontSize -> 12, 
   FontColor -> White\], "",
  TextCell\["WorldGDP in 2020", FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 20\],
  TextCell\["parameter domain:{1,2,3}", FontWeight -> Bold, 
   FontSize -> 12\], "",
  TextCell\["% Difference from baseline and contributions in % pts", 
   "TI"\],
  BarChart\[
   data,
   PlotTheme -> "Business",
   ChartLabels -> Placed\[countries, Below, Rotate\[#, Pi/2.4\] &\],
   ChartStyle -> {{Blue, Green}, None},
   ChartLegends -> {{"2019", "2020"}, None},
   ImageSize -> 500
   \]
  },
 Alignment -> Center,
 Background -> {Automatic, {1 -> Darker\[Red\], 2 -> Darker\[Red\]}}
 \]]
```

generates:

[image]

I want to create a chart combining the bars (for 2019 and 2020) as a single arrow from 2019 to 2020 as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `ChartElementFunction` but it might be easier to customize a `Graphics` than do that:

```
countries = CountryData["G7"];
data = {{2, 1, 1.5, 3, 3, 2.5, 4}, {-2, -1, -1.5, -3, -3, -2.5, -2}};

tdat = Transpose[{countries, data[[1]], data[[2]]}];
element[x_, country_, y1_, y2_] :=
 {Gray,
  Arrowheads[.05],
  With[{sz = .08},
   Rectangle[{x - sz, y1 - sz}, {x + sz, y1 + sz}]]
  , Arrow[{{x, y1}, {x, y2}}],
  Orange,
  Text[country["Name"], {x, y1 + .25}]
  }

Graphics[{
  MapIndexed[element[First@#2, #1[[1]], #1[[2]], #1[[3]]] &, tdat]
  }, Axes -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1 + Length@countries}, Automatic}, 
 Ticks -> {None, Automatic}, 
 FrameLabel -> {None, "GDP growth rate (%)"}, Frame -> True, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Orange, Dashing[{.003}]], 
 FrameTicks -> {None, Automatic}]
```

[image: gdp chart]

Comment: It is great. Is it possible to use labels as in the example given? Two labels are: Average GDP and Projected GDP.

Answer (score 3):

We can use the built-in (but undocumented) chart element function `"ArrowRectangle"` to create desired graphics primitives:

```
ClearAll[arrowBar]
arrowBar[arrowwidth_: .5, boxwidth_: 1, arrowangle_: 120][
  colors_: ColorData[97, "ColorList"], dr_: 5] := 
   {colors[[#]], Opacity[.7], 
    ChartElementData["ArrowRectangle", {"ArrowheadAngle" -> arrowangle, 
       "ArrowWidth" -> arrowwidth}][{{-boxwidth, boxwidth}/2 + #2, #3}], 
    Opacity[1], EdgeForm[Gray], Disk[{#2, #3[[1]]}, Offset[dr]]} &;
```

***Examples:***

```
Column[{
  Graphics[arrowBar[][{RandomColor[]}][1, #, 
      RandomSample @ {2, -2}] & /@ {1, 3, 5}],
  Graphics[arrowBar[1, .9 , 120][{RandomColor[]}, 7][1, #, 
      RandomSample @ {2, -2}] & /@ {1, 3, 5}],
  Graphics[arrowBar[.1, .9, 90][{RandomColor[]}, 10][1, #,
      RandomSample @ {2, -2}] & /@ {1, 3, 5}]}]
```

[image]

```
legend = Graphics[{arrowBar[][{Gray}][1, -1/4, {1, -1}/2] /.
    EdgeForm[_] -> EdgeForm[White],
   GrayLevel[.2], 
   Text[Style["actual", FontSize -> 11], Offset[{5, 0}, {1/8, 1/2}], Left], 
   Text[Style["projected", FontSize -> 11], Offset[{5, 5}, {1/8, -1/2}], Left]}, 
  ImageSize -> 1 -> 40]
```

[image]

Using a modification of data in OP:

```
countries = CountryData["G7"];
data = {{2, 1, 1.5, 3, 3, 2.5, 4}, {-2, -1, -1.5, -3, -3, -2.5, -2}};

SeedRandom[1]
data2 = Transpose[{#, # + RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, Length @ data[[1]]]} & @ data[[1]]];

options = Join[{ImageSize -> Large, Axes -> {True, False}, 
     AxesStyle -> Dashed, AspectRatio -> 1/2}, 
   FilterRules[Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Business", Plot], Options[Graphics]]];


Legended[Graphics[arrowBar[][] @@@ MapIndexed[{1, #2[[1]], #} &, data2], 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, 
   {Thread[{Range@Length@data2, Rotate[#, 90 Degree] & /@ countries}], Automatic}},
  options],
 legend]
```

[image]

Use `arrowBar[][] @@@ MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #2[[1]] , #} &, data2]` to get

[image]

To deal with grouped data, we need to pre-process input data into a form that can be used with `arrowBar`:

```
ClearAll[preProcess]
preProcess[groupsizes_List, groupspacing_: 1] := Join[Join @@ 
   MapIndexed[Thread @ {#2[[1]], (#2[[1]] - 1) groupspacing + # - 1} &, 
      TakeList[Range[Length@#], groupsizes]], List /@ #, 2] &;
```

Partition `data2` into two groups with sizes 3 and 4:

```
dt = preProcess[{3, 4}] @ data2;


Legended[Graphics[arrowBar[][ColorData[97] /@ {1, 2}] @@@ dt, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic},
    {Thread[{dt[[All, 2]], Rotate[#, 90 Degree] & /@ countries}], Automatic}}, 
   options], 
 Column[{SwatchLegend[Opacity[.7, #] & /@ ColorData[97] /@ {1, 2}, {"group1", 
     "group2"}], legend}]]
```

[image]

Partition `data2` into three groups with sizes 3,2 and 2:

```
dt = preProcess[{3, 2, 2}] @ data2;

colors = ColorData[97] /@ {1, 2, 3}; 

Legended[Graphics[arrowBar[][colors] @@@ dt, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, 
     {Thread[{dt[[All, 2]], Rotate[#, 90 Degree] & /@ countries}], Automatic}}, 
  options], 
 Column[{SwatchLegend[Opacity[.7, #] & /@ colors, 
   {"group1", "group2", "group3"}], legend}]]
```

[image]

Use `arrowBar[1, .9 , 120][colors, 15] @@@ dt` to get

[image]

Use `arrowBar[.1, 1/4 , 120][colors, 7] @@@ dt` to get

[image]

Comment: Very cool -- did not know about "ArrowRectangle"!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `BarChart` with a custom `ChartElementFunction`:

```
ClearAll[cEF]
cEF[dr_: 2, as_: .03] := 
   {Arrowheads[{{as, 0, Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], Disk[{0, 0}, Offset @ dr]}]}, as}], 
   Arrow[Thread[{Mean[#[[1]]], #3[[1]]}]]} &
```

***Examples:***

```
BarChart[Thread[data[[1]] -> Transpose[data]], 
 ChartStyle -> (ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale[-Subtract @@@ Transpose[data]]), 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[countries, Axis, Rotate[#, 90 Degree] &], 
 PlotRange -> {-4, 5}, PlotTheme -> "Business",
 ChartElementFunction -> cEF[]]
```

[image]

```
bc = BarChart[Thread[data[[1]] -> Transpose[data]], 
 ChartStyle -> (ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale[-Subtract @@@ Transpose[data]]), 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[countries, Axis, Rotate[#, 90 Degree] &], 
 PlotRange -> {-4, 5}, PlotTheme -> "Business",
 ChartElementFunction -> cEF[5, .05], 
 ChartBaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[4]]
```

[image]

Adding a legend:

```
legend = Graphics[{Red, AbsoluteThickness[3], 
   cEF[5, .5][{{0, 1/5}, {0, 1}}, {1}, {{1, -1}/5}], GrayLevel[.4], 
   Text[Style["actual", 12], Offset[{10, 0}, {1/10, 1/5}], Left], 
   Text[Style["projected", 12], Offset[{10, 10}, {1/10, -1/5}], Left]},  
   PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 80];

Legended[bc, legend]
```

[image]

Another example:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data2 = ({#, # + RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, Length@data[[1]]]} & @ data[[1]]);

BarChart[Thread[data2[[1]] -> Transpose[data2]], 
 ChartStyle -> (ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale[-Subtract @@@ Transpose[data2]]), 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[countries, Axis, Rotate[#, 90 Degree] &], 
 PlotRange -> {-5, 10}, PlotTheme -> "Business", 
 ChartElementFunction -> cEF[], 
 ChartBaseStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

**Update:**  *To present data in two groups "with less space in between individual country arrows in each group, and one color for each group but different across groups"*, pre-process input data to attach labels to each data element:

```
labeleddata2 = TakeDrop[#, 3] & @
   MapThread[Labeled[#, #2, Axis] -> #3 &, {data2[[1]], 
     Rotate[#, 90 Degree] & /@ countries, Transpose[data2]}];
```

To have different within-group and between-group bar spacings, use `BarSpacing -> {0, bs}` and adjust  horizontal `PlotRange` to prevent unwanted spaces on the left and right:

```
bs = 1;

Legended[BarChart[labeleddata2, 
    ChartLabels -> {{"\n\n\n\ngroup1", "\n\n\n\ngroup2"}, None}, 
    PlotTheme -> "Business", 
    ImageSize -> Large, 
    ChartElementFunction -> cEF[], 
    ChartStyle -> {{Orange, Blue}, None}, 
    ChartBaseStyle -> Thick, 
    BarSpacing -> {0, bs}, 
    PlotRange -> {{(bs + 1)/2, All}, All}],
 legend]
```

[image]

Add the option `ChartLegends -> SwatchLegend[{Orange, Blue}, {"group1", "group2"}]` to get:

[image]

To have input data in groups with each data element having its own label *and* style, pre-process input data to attach labels and styles to each data element:

```
labeledstyleddata2 = TakeDrop[#, 3] & @ MapThread[
  Labeled[Style[#, #2], #3, Axis] -> #4 &, {data2[[1]], 
   ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale[-Subtract @@@ Transpose[data2]], 
   Rotate[#, 90 Degree] & /@ countries, Transpose[data2]}]; 

bs = 1;

Legended[
  BarChart[labeledstyleddata2, 
    ChartLabels -> {{"\n\n\n\ngroup1", "\n\n\n\ngroup2"}, None}, 
    PlotTheme -> "Business", 
    ImageSize -> Large, 
    ChartElementFunction -> cEF[], 
    ChartBaseStyle -> Thick, 
    BarSpacing -> {0, bs}, 
    PlotRange -> {{(bs + 1)/2, All}, All}],
  legend]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for all the examples. All are very nice.

Comment: Sorry forgot to let you know. The legends for starting point and ending points are missing. For example, for Canada, it starts with a small circle and ends with an arrow (like others). These points are critical to show the projection and its direction. For a starting point, we can use the legend `Actual GDP` and for an ending point, the legend can be `Projected GDP`. You might want to see the example given in question.

Comment: @TugrulTemel, please see the update.

Comment: I know that `thanking` is not required in this forum, but somehow I feel something is missing if I do not `thank` you. Therefore, I thank you again.

Comment: Given the very last figure, can you guide me in presenting the very last figure with two groups: `gr1={Canada, France, Germany}`  and `gr2={the rest of the countries}`,  with less space in between individual country arrows in each group, and one color for each group but different across groups?

Comment: @TugrulTemel, please see the update.

Comment: Thanks for this. I use `bs=0.5` for a new chart but somehow nothing changes in the space between the vertical arrows.

Comment: I tried to adapt your code: ` arrowBar[.1, 1/4 , 120][colors, 7] @@@ dt` to simply replace the directed arrows with bars for each country, keeping the same groupings. I liked the presentation of your bar chart but wanted to use a bar for each country because sometimes I have data only for one year rather than two years. Where should I change to replace the bars (no arrows)?

Comment: @TugrulTemel, `arrowBar` needs input data with two height lists (like `data = {{2, 1, 1.5, 3, 3, 2.5, 4}, {-2, -1, -1.5, -3, -3, -2.5, -2}};`).  If the data is a single list of heights, say, `dataA = {2, 1, 1.5, 3, 3, 2.5, 4};`  then you can combine it with a list of 0s ( `dataB ={dataA, 0&/@dataA}`), pre-process if needed (e.g, `dt = preProcess[...]@dataB` ), and use  `180` as the arrowangle argument in `arrowBar` (e.g.,`arrowBar[1, .9, 180][colors, 7]@@@dt`). But for this case, `BarChart` would be  more straightforward to use.