# How to delete missing data and use the resulting database in a bar chart

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, charts, code-request

I want to construct a bar char for the following data, but I am having a problem with `Missing[]`:

```
countries = {"Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", "India", 
   "Maldives", "Nepal", "Pakistan", "Sri Lanka", "Brunei Darussalam", 
   "Cambodia", "Indonesia", "Laos", "Malaysia", "Myanmar", 
   "Philippines", "Singapore", "Thailand", "Timor-Leste", "Vietnam", 
   "China", "Japan", "Mongolia", "North Korea", "South Korea", 
   "American Samoa", "Fiji", "French Polynesia", "Guam", 
   "Hong Kong SAR, China", "Kiribati", "Marshall Islands", 
   "Micronesia", "Nauru", "New Caledonia", "Northern Mariana Islands",
    "Palau", "Papua New Guinea", "Samoa", "Solomon Islands", "Tonga", 
   "Tuvalu", "Vanuatu", "Australia", "New Zealand"};
sAsia = {"Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", "India", "Maldives", 
   "Nepal", "Pakistan", "Sri Lanka"};
seAsia = {"Brunei Darussalam", "Cambodia", "Indonesia", "Laos", 
   "Malaysia", "Myanmar", "Philippines", "Singapore", "Thailand", 
   "Timor-Leste", "Vietnam"};
eAsia = {"China", "Japan", "Mongolia", "North Korea", "South Korea"};
SIDS = {"American Samoa", "Fiji", "French Polynesia", "Guam", 
   "Hong Kong SAR, China", "Kiribati", "Marshall Islands", 
   "Micronesia", "Nauru", "New Caledonia", "Northern Mariana Islands",
    "Palau", "Papua New Guinea", "Samoa", "Solomon Islands", "Tonga", 
   "Tuvalu", "Vanuatu"};
Pacific = {"Australia", "New Zealand"};

data19 = {2.55, 8.05, 4.05, 5.25, 7.55, 7.15, 3.7, 2.8, 2, 7.25, 5.1, 
  5.5, 4.55, 6.6, 6.15, 2.4, 3.25, 0.35, 7.05, 6.25, 0.45, 6.2, 
  Missing[], 2.45, Missing[], 1.7, Missing[], Missing[], 0.8, 3.85, 
  4.8, 0.7, 3.35, Missing[], Missing[], 2, 2.8, 0.75, 2.55, 0.5, 4.6,
  3.1, 2.35, 2.9};
data20 = {-5, 3.8, -0.8, -8, -32.2, -1.9, -0.4, -3.6, 
  1.2, -3.5, -2.1, -0.4, -5.6, 3.2, -9.5, -5.4, -6.1, -6.8, 2.9, 
  2.3, -4.8, -5.3, Missing[], -1, Missing[], -19, Missing[], 
  Missing[], -6.1, -0.5, -3.3, -1.6, 0.7, Missing[], 
  Missing[], -10.3, -3.9, -3.2, -4.3, -0.5, 0.5, -9.2, -2.4, -3};
data = {data19, data20};
names = {"2019", "2020"};
ds = Dataset@Map[AssociationThread[names, #] &]@Transpose[data]
```

I like to use the database `ds` in constructing special charts in: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/249707/60365

Initially, I gave the data as a list of lists and I had no problem. But now because of the `Missing[]` observations in my data, I realized that using the database `ds` is more advantagous but then I am stuck with how touse `ds` in the `code` given in the above link.

Comment: `Select[FreeQ[_Missing]]@ds`?

Comment: .. or `DeleteMissing[ds, 1, Infinity]`?

Comment: @kglr: Your suggestion above works fine. But I wanted to use the new list of data (without `Missing[]`) in the chart by replacing `data` with `DeleteMissing[ds, 1, Infinity]`. When I do this, the predefined groups `preProcess[{8, 11, 5, 18, 2}]` may pose problems. I wanted to have no arrow bar (empty space) for the missing countries but keep the country names on the X-axis. This way I can control the countries with missing values.

Comment: @kglr: Sorry, the title of the question is misleading. I wanted to delete the missing observations and then use the resulting database in a bar chart.

Comment: There is no need to delete missing observations if we use a slightly modified version of `arrowBar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can slightly modify the function `arrowBar` from the linked answer so that it returns `{}` for inputs with `Missing` elements.

```
ClearAll[arrowBarB]
arrowBarB[arrowwidth_: .5, boxwidth_: 1, arrowangle_: 120][
   colors_: ColorData[97, "ColorList"], dr_: 5] := 
  If[FreeQ[#3, _Missing], {colors[[#]], Opacity[.7], 
     ChartElementData["ArrowRectangle", {"ArrowheadAngle" -> arrowangle, 
        "ArrowWidth" -> arrowwidth}][{{-boxwidth, boxwidth}/2 + #2, #3}], 
     Opacity[1], EdgeForm[Gray], Disk[{#2, #3[[1]]}, Offset[dr]]}, {}] &;
```

We use `preProcess` and `options` from the linked answer as is and change the labels in `legend`:

```
ClearAll[preProcess]
preProcess[groupsizes_List, groupspacing_: 1] := 
  Join[Join @@ MapIndexed[
      Thread @ {#2[[1]], (#2[[1]] - 1) groupspacing + # - 1} &, 
      TakeList[Range[Length @ #], groupsizes]], List /@ #, 2] &;

options = Join[{ImageSize -> Large, Axes -> {True, False}, 
    AxesStyle -> Dashed, AspectRatio -> 1/2}, 
   FilterRules[Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Business", Plot], Options[Graphics]]];

legend = Graphics[{arrowBarB[][{Gray}][1, -1/4, {1, -1}/2] /. 
     EdgeForm[_] -> EdgeForm[White],
    GrayLevel[.2], 
    Text[Style["2019", FontSize -> 11], Offset[{5, 0}, {1/8, 1/2}],  Left], 
    Text[Style["2020", FontSize -> 11], Offset[{5, 5}, {1/8, -1/2}], Left]}, 
    ImageSize -> 1 -> 40];

data3 = Normal @ Values[ds];

dt = preProcess[{8, 11, 5, 18, 2}, 3][data3];

groupnames = {"sAsia", "seAsia", "eAsia", "SIDS", "Pacific"};

groupcolors = ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length @ groupnames];
```

We color country labels red for countries with missing data:

```
missingpositions = Position[data3, _?(MatchQ[{_, _Missing} | {_Missing, _}])];

xticks = Thread[{dt[[All, 2]], Rotate[#, 90 Degree] & /@ 
     MapAt[Style[#, Red] &, countries, missingpositions]}];
```

We also add gridlines for each country to distinguish gaps due to missing elements from between-group gaps:

```
Legended[Graphics[arrowBarB[.1, .8, 120][groupcolors, 3] @@@ dt, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {xticks,  Automatic}}, 
  ImageSize -> 800, 
  LabelStyle -> Medium,
  GridLines -> {dt[[All, 2]], Automatic}, 
  options], 
 Column[{SwatchLegend[groupcolors, groupnames], legend}]]
```

[image]